# JsonMappingException Duplicate property ... for [simple type, class java.lang.Exception]

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to map a valid json string to a POJO with code that worked about 2 weeks ago.  **I have made no changes to the code in those 2 weeks.**

My json string is valid according to http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

I am using Jackson to map the json to the POJO:

```
response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(validJsonString, response.class);
```

This worked before! Now I get the following error.  Any insights would be appreciated.  I cannot find anything relating to this error message (in the title and first line of the stacktrace).

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Duplicate property 'cause' for [simple type, class java.lang.Exception]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:267)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:242)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:111)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.createCollectionDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:178)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:330)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:262)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:242)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:111)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:307)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.resolve(BeanDeserializer.java:246)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._resolveDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:346)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:301)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:242)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:111)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findTypedValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:127)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:1655)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1588)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1116)
at com.jpmorgan.wm.svc.client.coverage.WmSvcLogAnalytics.getMosaicTraceIdStatus(WmSvcLogAnalytics.java:178)
at com.jpmorgan.wm.svc.client.coverage.WmSvcLogAnalytics.getLogAnalyticsLogEventDetails(WmSvcLogAnalytics.java:118)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:168)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1357)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1289)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:944)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate property 'cause' for [simple type, class java.lang.Exception]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.addProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildThrowableDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:164)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:95)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:340)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:262)
... 56 more
```

Comment: Let's see your JSON and your target type.

Comment: But did you change version of JDK you use? I think JDK definition of `Exception` changed (for 1.7 maybe?), and included a new property.

Comment: @StaxMan we're still on 1.6

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for posting an answer without my json and target type. I did not post json or target type because this is company data.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it, minimally? The actual contents don't matter. It's the structure that does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I did just that - I created the exact test you provided in your answer, but I supplied my JSON. It serializes to the POJO perfectly.

Comment: Worth checking out, still, as something must have changed; behavior does not change on its own. But the other question is, which version of Jackson? 1.x something, but is there room for upgrade of patch version (or, minor)

Comment: That being said, there are complex data types in my POJO that are developed by other teams at the company.

Comment: @StaxMan The version of Jackson is 1.5

Comment: Ok. Latest from 1.5 is `1.5.8` so make sure it's at least that. But there 1.x versions all the way to `1.9`; and upgrade to at least `1.7` would be safe (`1.8` has some bigger changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not answer the question exactly as written, but is the final solution to my problem.

I have refactored my code, which ultimately has led to some code reduction.

I no longer map the JSON to a java object. After inspecting my code, I realized I do very little processing on the java object, before it is reseralied back into JSON and sent out of a Jersey REST service to the front end.

So I am now simply directly returning the JSON string as a `string` instead of a java object to be serialized into JSON by Jersey.

That being said, I still have no idea what the actual issue is (was).  I would still be open to hearing others' thoughts on the exception.  For now though, I have a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this problem myself and I found out that I had duplicate names in my `JsonProperty` annotations. In my case the bean that caused the error referenced a separate class where the actual typo was present:

```
@JsonProperty("attributes") Object attributes,
@JsonProperty("attributes") BoundingBox boundingBox,
...
```

After re-checking and fixing all the constructors I got it to work.

Bottom-line: Check your constructors!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that something has indeed changed for you; and based on my experience it could be upgrade of JSK -- definition of `Exception` did change between JDK 1.6 and 1.7.

But as to solving the problem, make sure you are using a recent version of Jackson. From class names, it looks like you are using Jackson 1.x (and not 2.x), so your choice of versions may be limited. But at least make sure to use the latest patch version of minor version you have (for example, if you were using 1.9.4, use latest 1.9 one, 1.9.13).
It is possible this particular problem has been fixed in a later patch version.